# DataGrid bound to ObservableCollection doesn't update when an Item is Removed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I have this WPF Application with four main views. One of the views, lets call it 'OrdersView', has a DataGrid that contains orders. The DataContext for this is a ViewModel, 'OrdersViewModel', that, of course, implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Each row of the grid has a button to see the details of the order. This button opens a new Window through a Window service that allows the user to update the order by processing it, adding more items or deleting the order. This window holds a UserControl named 'OrderDetailsView' that of course has a 'OrderDetailsViewModel' as DataContext. I have no issues with the 'edit order' and 'process order' functionalities. The problem is the 'Delete Order'. This button is bound to a command in the ViewModel that raises an event and sends the order Id to a listener in the application Main window, then the Main window passes this Id to a method in the 'OrdersViewModel' that has a function to find the order in the ObservableCollection and removes it.
The item is removed, I have seen the Collection changing in the debugger, but when the 'OrderDetailsView' is closed, the Orders DataGrid still have the bloody order and it only gets refreshed when I navigate to a different view and go back to it.
I have tried to put the RaisePropertyChanged method in the setter of the collection, at the end of the delete method with the name of the property Orders and doesn't work.

Data Grid starts like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Orders}"
              Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}">
```

The ViewDetails button is:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Button x:Name="BtnOrderDetails"
                      Content="View"
                      Margin="1"
                      Command="{Binding DataContext.SeeOrderDetailsCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
```

The OrdersViewModel is something like:

```
public class OrdersViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Order> _orders;

        public OrdersViewModel(List<Order> orders)
        {
            Orders = new ObservableCollection<Order>(orders);
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders
        {
            get => _orders;
            set
            {
                _orders = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public void DeleteOrder(int id)
        {
            Orders.Remove(Orders
                .FirstOrDefault(order => order.Id.Equals(id)));
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Orders));
        }
    }
```

The View details button takes you to a new window that holds the 'OrderDetailsView' and has a button like this:

```
<Button x:Name="DeleteOrder"
              Content="Delete order"
              Grid.Row="2"
              Margin="10,0,0,10"
              Style="{StaticResource DeleteOrderButton}"
              Command="{Binding DeleteOrderCommand}"/>
```

In the view model for this view I have the following:

```
public DelegateCommand DeleteOrderCommand { get; private set; }
```

and in the constructor:

```
DeleteOrderCommand = new DelegateCommand(DeleteOrder, () => CanDelete);
```

The method raises an event (is that how you say it?):

```
private void DeleteOrder()
{
    DeleteOrderRequested(Order.Id);
    CloseWindow();
}

public event Action<int> DeleteOrderRequested = delegate { };
```

My main Window that is the thing that communicates the different view model catches this event:

```
private void OnDeleteOrderRequested(int id)
{
    OrdersViewModel.DeleteOrder(id);
}
```

It's sort of a stupidly complex application for what it does, I know, right?

Why, why, why the view is not getting notified that an item has been removed???

Can someone please help? Or at least tell me where to continue looking?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: It's difficult to understand how your logic works as you chose to only post loose code snippets. You should check if the command is invoked and you listen to the event and you call delete on the proper instance - make sure you are using only a single OrdersViewModel  instance. The way you have defined the event delegate is very unconventional. You should use `Eventhandler<TEventArgs>` instead. But more important consider to let your OrdersViewModel expose the OrdersDetailsViewModel for the currently selected order. This can significantly simplify the logic and very likely solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Totally agree, it's just too much code, just doesn't feel right to paste 200 lines of code to explain what the viewModel does. I have no idea how to use the eventHandler that you mentioned, I will look into it though, promise. Anyway, I found the problem. Had to do with the assignment of the currentViewModel at startup. Too long to explain here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I handled the navigation with a not so elegant switch statement that switches the CurrentViewModel in the MainWindow and it gets changed with data templates, so when the VM changes the View changes. Probably not very conventional, it kinda works. The problem is that at startup I assigned the CurrentViewModel to the OrdersViewModel and then put that viewModel in a Property to use it later when I wanted to go back. So I should have done it the other way around, which I did already, so when the app starts, I first create the OrderViewModel, put in a property and then I assigned the currentVM to that VM. I noticed that this was the problem because the delete function actually worked when I navigated away from the first view and then went back.
The MainWindowViewModel was like this:

```
 public MainWindowViewModel(IOrdersDataProvider ordersData, ViewModelBase currentViewModel, AddItemViewModel addItemViewModel, ViewModelFactory vMFactory)
{
    _Data = ordersData;
    _isModalOpen = false;
    _currentViewModel = currentViewModel;
    _addItemViewModel = addItemViewModel;
    NavigateCommand = new RelayCommandT<string>(Navigate, () => OrderDetailsWindowsOpen);
    SeeOrderDetailsCommand = new DelegateCommand<Order>(ViewOrderDetails);
    CreateNewOrderCommand = new DelegateCommand(CreateNewOrder);
    _vMFactory = vMFactory;
}
```

And the a ComposeObjects method in app.xaml.cs was doing something very silly like:

```
private static void ComposeObjects(ViewModelFactory vMFactory)
{
    var currentViewModel = vMFactory.CreateViewModel("Orders");
    var addOrderViewModel = vMFactory.CreateViewModel("AddOrder");
    var mainWindowViewModel = (MainWindowViewModel)vMFactory.CreateViewModel("MainWindow");
    // Set up main ViewModel
    mainWindowViewModel.AddOrderViewModel = (AddOrderViewModel)addOrderViewModel;
    mainWindowViewModel.OrdersViewModel = (OrdersViewModel)currentViewModel;
    mainWindowViewModel.SubscribeHandlersToEvents();
    Application.Current.MainWindow = new MainWindow
    {
        DataContext = mainWindowViewModel
    };
}
```

I changed it like this:

```
private static void ComposeObjects(ViewModelFactory vMFactory)
{
    // Get ViewModels
    var addOrderViewModel = vMFactory.CreateViewModel("AddOrder");
    var mainWindowViewModel = (MainWindowViewModel)vMFactory.CreateViewModel("MainWindow");
    // Set up main ViewModel
    mainWindowViewModel.AddOrderViewModel = (AddOrderViewModel)addOrderViewModel;
    mainWindowViewModel.SubscribeHandlersToEvents();
    Application.Current.MainWindow = new MainWindow
    {
        DataContext = mainWindowViewModel
    };
}
```

And I adjusted the MainWindowVM constructor to:

```
 public MainWindowViewModel(IOrdersDataProvider ordersData, ViewModelBase ordersViewModel, AddItemViewModel addItemViewModel, ViewModelFactory vMFactory)
{
    _Data = ordersData;
    _isModalOpen = false;
    OrdersViewModel = (OrdersViewModel)ordersViewModel;
    _currentViewModel = OrdersViewModel;
    _addItemViewModel = addItemViewModel;
    NavigateCommand = new RelayCommandT<string>(Navigate, () => OrderDetailsWindowsOpen);
    SeeOrderDetailsCommand = new DelegateCommand<Order>(ViewOrderDetails);
    CreateNewOrderCommand = new DelegateCommand(CreateNewOrder);
    _vMFactory = vMFactory;
}
```

Assigning OrdersViewModel property first did the trick, of course, is messy, its a work in progress, I will implement a container like Ninject in the next days.
I can go to sleep now.